# ASP MVC and postgres

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, postgresql

there's any tutorial who explains how to use asp mvc with postgres? (or any other db who don't be MSSQL)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's two ways you can go.

1. You can use a data provider like
   this: 
   http://npgsql.projects.postgresql.org/exampleprograms.html
2. You can use a LINQ provider for
   Postgres similar to this: 
   http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/linq.html?gclid=CP7V6ePG6ZsCFSMSagodlWxx5Q

Here's a code project article describing how to use the data provider:  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/afppostgresqlintro.aspx

Comment: While this answer may theoretically answer the question, [it is better](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I have to use a webservice as data source, i make a wrapper for the webservices and put all the data in lists, so i can use linq with them. Then use all existing tutorials for MVC.